# How do install AzureAD PowerShell module

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory

When I try to install the AzureAD module I get the following error:

```
Import-Module -Name AzureAD
```

> Import-Module : The specified module 'AzureAD' was not loaded because
>   no valid module file was found in any module directory.

Comment: `Import-Module` is the cmdlet used to load a module that has already been installed on your system. You should read up on `Find-Module` and `Install-Module`. You can get some more info on both installing modules and this very module in question here <https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/AzureAD/2.0.2.26>

Answer (score 10):

`Import-Module` loads a PowerShell module which you have already installed on your system. It looks like in your case, the module hasn't been installed yet.

To install Azure AD PowerShell, you need to use `Install-Module`:

```
Install-Module -Name "AzureAD"
```

If you would like to install the module to the current user (i.e. without administrator privileges), you can do this:

```
Install-Module -Name "AzureAD" -Scope CurrentUser
```

The documentation for the Azure AD PowerShell module (and how to install it) is at: https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/azure/active-directory/install-adv2?view=azureadps-2.0#installing-the-azure-ad-module